# Inline SVG to fil CSS grid cell, ignoring aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using inline SVG to render content (for a game, if it makes any difference). I'm going to be adjusing the viewBox through javascript, so I don't care about maintating the aspect ratio of the outer svg element.

I've included a demo below stripped down to the minimum - a CSS grid with a nested SVG element.

The problem is that when I load the demo and make the browser wider, the SVG element gets taller as well. How do I keep the SVG filling the main element, without it pushing the footer off the screen?

```
    <head>
        <title>SVG scale demo</title>
        <style>
            html,
            body {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            body {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-rows: 3em 1fr 3em;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 10em;
                grid-template-areas: "Header Header""Main Aside""Footer Footer"
            }

            svg {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            header {
                grid-area: Header;
            }

            main {
                grid-area: Main
            }

            aside {
                grid-area: Aside
            }

            footer {
                grid-area: Footer
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header> Header content </header>
        <main>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="-10 -10 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="8" />
            </svg>
        </main>
        <aside> Side bar content </aside>
        <footer> Footer content </footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

I've tried various combinations of setting width/height in CSS and on the svg element, and I've added the preserveAspectRatio attribute to the svg element, and now I'm asking you folks for help.

Comment: Are you sure that you want the viewBox settings to be viewBox="-10 -10 20 20"?  the -10 -10 are offsets for x and y and mean the svg starts from co-ordinates (-10px,-10px). usually the viewBox is set to "0 0 x y"

Comment: yeah, I want the SVG origin to be at the center of the viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh. Looks like I need to add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the CSS for main.